# Component within a component in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

By using `React.createClass` we know we can have `React.createClass` within createClass, just assign it to a function, says the name is Abc then it can be used like `<Abc someprop/>`

but how bout in ES6?

view-source:http://chrisharrington.github.io/demos/react-controls/calendar.html

I'm trying to convert line `var Week = React.createClass({..` in es6 but don't know how.

Comment: `class Week extends React.Component {...}`. This syntax is well documented. Please close this question.

Comment: @AndyRay class within class?

Comment: @AlexYong you create a class, then import that class in another class and use it the same way, i.e. `<Abc ... />`. You need to do your research.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "Component within component", but did you read the React documentation? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: @FelixKling I read but I don't always remember.

Comment: What do you mean by "*just assign it to a function*"? A function can only be called, not assigned to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of 2 react components, one inside the other one.

```js
import React from "react";

class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Foo component, title is: {this.props.title}</p/>
    );
  }
}

class Bar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Foo title="My title" />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ok I got it now. it's ok to have 2 class within one file.

Comment: You can do it, but it's not recommended. If you are using the ES6 syntax, you can have another react component in another file and importing it like this `import MyComponent from './my/path/MyComponent';`